# Bayesian choice, incorrect line in the book

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

[Here](http://leteckaposta.cz/341817187) (Large file) on the page 249, in the Example 5.3.12
isn't there a typo on the last but one line:
$$...$$
$$=P^X(|X|>|x|),X \sim\cal N(0,1)$$
$$=1-\Phi(|x|)+\Phi(|x|)=2[1-\Phi(|x|)]$$

Comment: There is no Example 5.3.12 nor is there a formula like you show on page 249 of the file at your link.

Comment: Sorry, a typo occurred.And now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a typo. The correction is in red:
$$
=1-\Phi(|x|)+\Phi(\color{red}{-}|x|)=2[1-\Phi(|x|)]
$$
Reasoning: $|x|$ is a positive quantity (actually non-negative), so $P(|X|>|x|)$ can be written as $$P(|X|>|x|)=P(X>|x|) + P(X<-|x|).$$ Expressed in terms of the cdf $\Phi$, the first entity is $$P(X>|x|)=1-\Phi(|x|)$$ and the second is $$P(X<-|x|)=\Phi(-|x|).$$

Alternatively, $P(|X|>|x|)$ is twice $P(X>|x|)$, which gets you immediately to $2[1-\Phi(|x|)]$, skipping the intermediate step.

Comment: Does it make any difference whether $|x|$ is positive or non-negative?Where it does the difference?

Comment: @user122424 It doesn't really make a difference. The only case where $|x|$ is not positive is the case $x=0$.

Comment: It does not make the difference even in the strict inequalities $P(X<-|x|)$?

Comment: @user122424 Correct. Since $X$ is a continuous random variable there is no difference between probabilities with strict and non-strict inequalities. Example: $P(|X|>|x|)$ and $P(|X|\ge |x|)$ are the same thing.